# Detecting uninitialized arrays

Tags: compiler-errors, initialization, fortran, runtime-error

In the following program, the two routines `set_int_array` and `set_real_array` define some values to dummy arrays, but suppose that the initialization of `a(:)` and `r(:)` (Lines 1 and 2) is missing inadvertently (i.e., both lines should be uncommented in the correct program). My question is how to detect these errors automatically with some compiler option(s).

```
module mymod
implicit none
contains

subroutine set_int_array ( a )
    integer, intent(out) :: a(:)
    integer k
    ! a(:) = 10                              !! (1)

    do k = 1, size(a)
        a(k) = a(k) + k
    enddo
end subroutine

subroutine set_real_array ( r )
    real, intent(out) :: r(:)
    integer k
    ! r(:) = 10.0                            !! (2)

    do k = 1, size(r)
        r(k) = r(k) + k
    enddo
end subroutine

end module

program main
    use mymod
    implicit none
    integer :: a(5)
    real    :: r(5)

    call set_int_array  ( a ) ; print *, a(:)
    call set_real_array ( r ) ; print *, r(:)
end program
```

To do so, I first tried the following option for gfortran4.8 (on Linux x86_64):

```
gfortran -Wall -fcheck=all test.f90
```

but this failed to detect the missing initialization and gave the incorrect result

```
           1           2   268435459       32730         207
   1.0000000       2.0000000       3.0000000       4.0000000       5.0000000
```

So I tried the following option to initialize `r(:)` with `NaN`:

```
gfortran -finit-real=snan -ffpe-trap=invalid test.f90
```

which successfully caught the error for `set_real_array`, but not for `set_int_array`

```
 -1098847551          59 -1034862589       32608        7941

Program received signal 8 (SIGFPE): Floating-point exception.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x00000039becac5f4 in wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000039c501400d in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
#2  0x00000039c501582e in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
#3  0x00000039c50146ca in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x0000000000400bd3 in __mymod_MOD_set_real_array ()
#6  0x0000000000400e69 in MAIN__ ()
#7  0x0000000000400f52 in main ()
```

As such, I also tried ifort14.0 with the following options

```
ifort -check all test.f90
ifort -check uninit test.f90
```

but both failed to detect the errors. Indeed, the man page for `check uninit` option says

> Only local *scalar* variables of intrinsic type INTEGER, REAL, COMPLEX, and LOGICAL without the SAVE attribute are checked.

then it may be natural that the errors are not detected. So my question is: Is there any method to catch both the errors for `a(:)` and `r(:)` automatically?

---

[ Edit ] My motivation for this question comes from [a recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975067/fortran-program-fails-depending-on-a-write-statement-before-subroutine-call) on SO, where the OP had a hard time for finding a bug. It turned out that the problem comes from the use of an uninitialized array in `curve_derivs_alg1()` in the `evaluate` module, but it was very tough for me also to find the precise location of the bug (although it may appear trivial once it is found!). The `-finit-real-snan -ffpe-trap=invalid` option works in this case, but it should become much more difficult if integer arrays were the problem... So I was wondering if there is some convenient options or ways to track the first location of the use of uninitialized arrays.

Comment: I don't have the resources here to write an answer but I suspect that it is relevant that `a(:)` is not (in an executable statement) an array but an array section.  There *is* a difference.  One impact of the difference is that automatic allocation can be performed with an array on the lhs of an assignment, but is invalid with an array section on the lhs.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Hi thank you very much for your comment. I am sorry if my explanation in the question was misleading, but I did not try to use allocatable dummy arrays in the two routines. They are simply passed from the main program (in which they are declared as local arrays). Here, what I am looking for is a convenient way to find the first location where uninitialized arrays are used (please see Edit above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Linux, you could use `valgrind` for this task. If you issue

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out
```

you will get a lot of output ;-) The first warning actually points towards the uninitialized variable:

```
==4426== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4426== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4426== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4426== Command: ./a.out
==4426== 
==4426== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4426==    at 0x4F29774: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0)
==4426==    by 0x4F2B2DE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0)
==4426==    by 0x4F1F126: _gfortran_transfer_array (in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0)
==4426==    by 0x40098B: MAIN__ (test.F90:34)
==4426==    by 0x400A75: main (test.F90:28)
==4426==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4426==    at 0x4008CD: MAIN__ (test.F90:27)
```

To better analyze the output, I prefer to have one statement per line, so I changed the last lines of your program to

```
    call set_int_array  ( a )
    print *, a(:)
    call set_real_array ( r )
    print *, r(:)
```

Then, `test.F90:34` points towards

```
    print *, a(:)
```

Later on, you will find the following output which points towards the second use of an uninitialized variable:

```
==4426== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4426==    at 0x4F27BC1: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0)
==4426==    by 0x4F2A6E4: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0)
==4426==    by 0x4F2B29E: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0)
==4426==    by 0x4F1F126: _gfortran_transfer_array (in /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0)
==4426==    by 0x400A44: MAIN__ (test.F90:36)
==4426==    by 0x400A75: main (test.F90:28)
==4426==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==4426==    at 0x4008CD: MAIN__ (test.F90:27)
```

Note that you will need to compile your code with debug options to get the line numbers. With `valgrind` it is also beneficial to correct one error after the other, starting from the first. This is because undefined behavior might cause subsequent errors/warnings that are gone once you fix the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your info. Up to now I have few experiences with valgrind (only used it a few times for checking memory leaks of some buggy C utility programs), so I had never used it for this purpose. And yes, it seems very useful to show the existence of uninitialized arrays in Fortran :)

Comment: So I have experimented it for [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975067/fortran-program-fails-depending-on-a-write-statement-before-subroutine-call/33976639#33976639). I tackled this problem yesterday on SO and experienced unexpectedly a hard time to find the bug. I have just tried valgrind for this code now, and it gives tons of error, but *only* after the print statement of the uninitialized values in the main program. As such, I was able to know that a bug exists in `__evaluate_MOD_rat_curve_derivs`, but not further down into a specific lower subroutine... (cont.)

Comment: I would like to trace this kind of bug (where the uninitialized variable is used in the first place), so if such technique exists, I really appreciate any hints. (Or I will turn this into a Question if necessary, though I am not sure how to make a good question...) But anyway, thanks very much for your info :)

Comment: @roygvib So far, I have not found a single method to *find them, to bring them all and in the darkness bind them*. It is usually a combination of tools... I have `-finit-real=snan -ffpe-trap=invalid` (and a few others) in my default compile options, and if they don't indicate a bug, I use tools like valgrind.

Comment: Hmm I see... and it is good to know that the usage of the -finit-real... option is reasonable. I will check more options of valgrind and try to get used to the usage. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If detecting such error is important to your work, you might want to invest in the NAG compiler which can report such problem at runtime. For example, if I save your original code in 'test.f90' and compile it:

```
nagfor test.f90 -C=undefined -o test.exe
```

At runtime I get the following:

```
Runtime Error: test.f90, line 11: Reference to undefined variable A(K)
Program terminated by fatal error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I uncomment and fix the first error, the second one is reported as well:

```
11 12 13 14 15
Runtime Error: test.f90, line 21: Reference to undefined variable R(K)
Program terminated by fatal error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Compilers do not normally perform this kind of check because it can be expensive. There are some limitations as well. More information is available at http://www.nag.co.uk/nagware/np/r60_doc/nagfor.html#UNDEF

Note that the answer is from a NAG person. The above link gives information on limitations on the use of '-C=undefined' flag, which is not directly related to this question but may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks @macelee, NAG fortran seems very strict in syntax checking. I will try to see whether I can use it somehow. Thanks :)