# catching uninitialized allocatable arrays in FORTRAN 90

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I am compiling with gfortran 5.4.1 and ifort 17.0.1

In the following code:

```
program check
   implicit none
   real, dimension(:), allocatable :: hello
   real :: g,h,i
   allocate(hello(5))
   g = hello(1)
   h = g + 10.0
   i = hello(2)*5
   print *, hello,g,h
end program check
```

We allocate the hello array, but never initialize it. we then use this uninitialized array to set a value, do two calculations, then print it all.

In my mind none of this should work. What is hello(1)? From execution of the code the entire array is being set to zero. Further, how can I find the mistake? When I compile with -Wall (gfortran) and -warn uninitialized -O0 (ifort) the code runs and compiles fine.

Anyone know what I am missing??

Comment: Welcome, see [ask]. Have you searched for previous answers? This question is very similar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978485/detecting-uninitialized-arrays Is there anything you want that is not there (**tell us what exactly**) or should I close your question as duplicate?

Comment: The compiler is not required by the standard to diagnose this kind of error. See the link for various ways how to find the use of uninitialized variables.

Comment: In addition to those answers you can also read external articles for specific compilers like https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/detection-of-uninitialized-floating-point-variables-in-intel-fortran it just takes a short search with Google.